# How can I insert array elements into SQLite table by index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sql-insert

Seems like array element index isn't a type that SQLite INSERT will allow.

```
contact[0] = raw_input("Last Name: ")
contact[1] = raw_input("First Name: ")
contact[2] = raw_input("Street Address: ")
contact[3] = raw_input("City: ")
contact[4] = raw_input("State: ")
contact[5] = raw_input("Zip Code: ")
contact[6] = raw_input("Phone: ")
contact[7] = raw_input("Email: ")

cur.execute("INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES(contact[0], contact[1], contact[2], contact[3], contact[4], contact[5], contact[6], contact[7])")
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making it a bit cleaner:

```
labels = [
    "Last Name: ", 
    "First Name: ", 
    "Street Address: ", 
    "City: ", 
    "State: ",
    "Zip Code: ",
    "Phone: ",
    "Email: "
]
contact = [raw_input(label) for label in labels]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", contact)
```

where `?` are [placeholders for query parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).